# How to create a public Multi-Region Access Point policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-access-points

I am experimenting with multi-region access points and their over-complicated policy syntax, and I can't get the simplest things to work.

I have 3 buckets spawned across the globa and created a single access point. All my items are private as my multi-region access point policy is not configured yet.

So far I have this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3::<my account id>:accesspoint/xyz.mrap"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:DataAccessPointAccount": "<my account id>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The error indicated states:

> Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

Their [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-policies.html) uses `"Action" : "*",` but I want to limit this.

Can anyone help out what is wrong with my policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s3:GetObject` applies to **objects only**. Your `arn:aws:s3::<my account id>:accesspoint/xyz.mrap` represents access point, not its objects. Thus it should be:

```
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3::<my account id>:accesspoint/xyz.mrap/*"
            ],
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the resource, and `"Action": "*",`  and it still says: `Policy has invalid resource`. I copied the ARN from above the policy input field and added `/*`, so no typo.

Comment: It seems to continue without the /* though. Now it's an access denied, so I accept your answer and go further down the rabbit hole. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-policies.html#access-points-policy-examples), the access point policy needs the `/object/*` prefix:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3::123456789012:accesspoint/xyz.mrap",
                "arn:aws:s3::123456789012:accesspoint/xyz.mrap/object/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It looks like you are trying to grant public access with a principal of `"AWS": "*"`, the steps to review:

1. Ensure your MRAP is created with public access block off
2. Delegate permissions from your buckets up to your MRAP, per [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-policies.html#access-points-delegating-control), ensuring the bucket is not getting in the way
3. Create the MRAP Policy to suit

Comment: What about the buckets, are they created with public access block off too? 
By `off` I guess you mean `true`.